# Calculate Monthly Average With Multiple Records in a Month

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, average

I have a dataset with the structure below.
I want to calculate a monthly average of the views.

[image]

I attempted to calculate the yearly frequency with the following code and I believe it is correct

```
SELECT 
EXTRACT (YEAR FROM TO_DATE("date",'Month YYYY') ) AS "year",
AVG("views")
FROM talks
GROUP BY EXTRACT (YEAR FROM TO_DATE("date",'Month YYYY') )
ORDER BY "year" DESC
```

When it comes to the monthly analysis I have the problem that there several records for the same month in a year and there several years with the same months (in reality the dataset has information for many years - this a reduced version).

How can I go to implement this?

Comment: Please update your question. First post your sample data as formatted text not as an image. See [Why should I not upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).Even better create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14). Secondly, having several rows for the same month and the same  months over several year seems pretty standard for analysis.  What exactly is the problem this causes?

Comment: Thank you your reply and the improvement suggestions! I will keep them in mind when asking questions in the future. I was not aware of this because I was using the same methodology and extracting the month it would give me the result regerdless of the year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the average per month then just group by your current *date* field.
If you want the average per month regardless of year then you would have to extract the month part of the current *date* field and group by that.

But your date field now appears to be having **string** data type; it would be better to use proper **date** data type. Then your analysis would be much easier, more flexible, better performing.

Comment: Thank you! In fact I was compicating trying to extract the month and I was getting the result regardless of the month. By grouping by the data solves my problem.